# How to excerpt div from foreach structure

Tags: php

I want to use the div only once in foreach structure because when it is used multiple times, images found are each on new line. I don't know how to excerpt div from it to use it only one time.

```
<?php
include('func.php');

if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){
    $suffix = "";
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));
    $errors = array();
        $results = search_results($keywords);
        if ($results === false) {
        echo '<h1>We didn\'t find anything for &quot;'.$keywords.'&quot;</h1>';
    }
    else {
        $results_num = count($results);
        $suffix = ($results_num!=1)?'s':'';
        echo '<h1>',$results_num,' item',$suffix,' For &quot;',$keywords,'&quot;</h1>';
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo '
<div style="background:rgba(50,0,100,1)">

<span class="overimage">

<a href="',$result['game_url'],'" target="_blank">

<span class="hoverimage">
<span class="hovertext1line-home">',$result['name'],'</span><img class="onlinegameimage-home" src="',$result['image_url'],'" alt=',$result['alt'],'>
</span>

</a>

</span>

</div>

';

}}}

?>
```

Comment: So the span can repeat? you want to restrict only the div right?

Comment: Yes, span can repeat.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the div tags outside of the foreach loop:

```
<?php
include('func.php');

if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    $suffix = "";
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['keywords'])));
    $errors = array();
        $results = search_results($keywords);
        if ($results === false) {
        echo '<h1>We didn\'t find anything for &quot;'.$keywords.'&quot;</h1>';
    } else {
        $results_num = count($results);
        $suffix = ($results_num!=1)?'s':'';
        echo '<h1>' . $results_num . ' item' . $suffix . ' For &quot;' . $keywords . '&quot;</h1>';
        echo '<div style="background:rgba(50,0,100,1)">';
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<span class="overimage">
                <a href="' . $result['game_url'] . '" target="_blank">
                    <span class="hoverimage">
                        <span class="hovertext1line-home">' . $result['name'] . '</span>
                        <img class="onlinegameimage-home" src="' . $result['image_url'] . '" alt="' . $result['alt'] . '" />
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Also fixed a lot of this code because it was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Also note that you are concatenating variable using comma (,) instead of dot (.). So change that too.

```
$div = '<div style="background:rgba(50,0,100,1)">';

foreach($results as $result){
   $div .= '<span class="overimage"><a href="'.$result['game_url'].'" target="_blank"><span class="hoverimage"><span class="hovertext1line-home">'.$result['name'].'</span><img class="onlinegameimage-home" src="'.$result['image_url'].'" alt='.$result['alt'].'></span></a></span>';
}

$div .= '</div>';
echo $div;
```